# How to sort a list of unique_ptrs?

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, move-semantics

I'm trying to write a function that creates a Huffman tree (as part of creating a Huffman encoding).

The function receives a `std::vector` of `unique_ptr`s to `Node` objects that contain information about the character, its frequency and left and right sons (`unique_ptr`s to other `Node`s).

In essence, what I want to do is move all the objects to a `std::list` if their frequency is more than 0, then sort the list, and then continue with an algorithm that will build the tree (which is out of the scope of this question).

I've managed to correctly use `std::copy_if` after a lot of trying to get it to work on move-only objects, but I'm having trouble with sorting the result.

In the following code `NodePtr` is an alias for `std::unique_ptr<Node>` and `NodeVector` is an alias for `std::vector<NodePtr>`:

```cpp
HuffmanEncoderDecoder::NodePtr &HuffmanEncoderDecoder::buildPrefixlessTree(NodeVector &frequencies) {
    std::list<NodePtr> sortedFrequencies;

    // Copy to list only if the character appeared at least once
    std::copy_if(std::make_move_iterator(frequencies.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(frequencies.end()),
        sortedFrequencies.begin(), [](NodePtr &&node) { return node->frequency != 0; });

    // Sort the list by ascending order of frequency
    std::sort(sortedFrequencies.begin(), sortedFrequencies.end(), [](const NodePtr &n1, const NodePtr &n2)
    { return n1->frequency <= n2->frequency; });

    // ...
}
```

I'm using `clang++`, which outputs the following error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::_List_iterator<std::unique_ptr<HuffmanEncoderDecoder::Node,
      std::default_delete<HuffmanEncoderDecoder::Node> > >' and 'std::_List_iterator<std::unique_ptr<HuffmanEncoderDecoder::Node, std::default_delete<HuffmanEncoderDecoder::Node> > >')
      if (__last - __first > int(_S_threshold))
          ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure if it's a move semantics issue, or something else I'm missing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::sort` requires random-access iterators. Your container `std::list<NodePtr> sortedFrequencies` does not provide random-access iterators - only bidirectional ones.

`std::list` has a member function named `sort` which will work for you, though. See [cppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort)

Comment: BTW, your comparison function probably does not provide a strict weak ordering: `{ return n1->frequency <= n2->frequency; }` because it returns true for the same object twice (`comp(a, a)` should return `false`)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! Do you think it will be more efficient to sort the original vector, and only then call `copy_if`?

Comment: Don't know - how big is your list? If it's small, then it probably will make no (measurable) difference.

Comment: It is small. In my case I know that I can have a maximum of 256 `char`s, so the frequencies vector is always of this size (I use a `vector` rather than an `array` because I use `std::generate` to init each `Node` with its own character). This is also why I use `std::copy_if` (to not copy `char`s with 0 frequency). But the question was more for the generalized case.